# How to Authenticate for Active Directory Users?

Tags: active-directory, flutter

I am building app for our Organization where in we need to enable the login screen and authenticate the user/pass against MS Active Directory.

Any help with sample code will be very helpful.

I am using Flutter to build mobile application

Comment: What language? What have you tried so far? Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ah my bad, I thought tags were already added. I am building mobile app with Flutter.